# rescaling xymatrix diagram is not sufficient to resize

Tags: diagrams, size, resize, xymatrix

Hi I have the begining of the following diagram but it doesn't work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{%
    \xymatrix{
        \mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}}(hom(q_{2}F_{1},q_{1}F_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{23}}}(hom(q_{2}G_{1},q_{1}G_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2})))\ar[d]&\\
        L\circ K (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}\times\Delta_{M_{23}}\times\Delta_{M_{34}}}(F_{1}\otimes G_{1}\otimes H_{1}, F_{2}\otimes G_{2} H_{2}))&L\circ K (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}\times\Delta_{M_{23}}}(F_{1}\otimes G_{1}, F_{2}\otimes G_{2}))\times\mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2}))
    }%
}
\]
```

I constantly have a message "dimension too large"?. Someone has an idea on how to fix this ?

\end{document}

UPDATE :

I try to edit with t

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzcd}
\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}}(hom(q_{2}F_{1},q_{1}F_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{23}}}(hom(q_{2}G_{1},q_{1}G_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2})))\arrow[d]&\\
L\circ K (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}\times\Delta_{M_{23}}\times\Delta_{M_{34}}}(F_{1}\otimes G_{1}\otimes H_{1}, F_{2}\otimes G_{2} H_{2}))&L\circ K (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}\times\Delta_{M_{23}}}(F_{1}\otimes G_{1}, F_{2}\otimes G_{2}))\times\mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2}))
\end{tikzcd}%
}
\]
\end{document}
```

And now I get an error message `Undefined control sequence. }` and the diagram is completely collapsing.

Comment: (1) Welcome,  (2) please make sure your MWE even has a chance of compiling! You're missing `\end{document}`, once that is added you'll notice that LaTeX complains that you have not defined `\resizebox` (add `graphicx`). Third, even when `\resizebox` is defined you still get `dimension too large` so your problem has nothing to do with rescaling (out comment the rescaling and you'll still get the error)

Comment: The real problem is the cells being too wide for `xymatrix` to handle, and `xymatrix` needs to handle its stuff before `\resizebox` can do its thing. You'll either need to rewrite this or switch to using `tikz-cd` instead of `xymatric` (IMO `tikz-cd` diagrams looks better)

Comment: ok thank you very much for those helpful elements

Comment: @daleif I updated my post, after using as y ou advised `tikz-cd`, but it is not working

Comment: `tikz-cd` is a different package that you do not load in this MWE, plus the arrow notation is different. Please read the `tikz-cd` manual

Comment: @daleif sorry, yes I corrected the arrow, and I already loaded the right package. But it still get the same error.

Comment: `&` parsing inside macro often goes haywire, use `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]` and replace the cell marking `&` by `\&`. Also note how my answer below uses `\hom`

Comment: @daleif oh thank you, that was not simple to see ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work, but looks bad. I'd recommend doing a rewrite, for example: "For the same of brevity let `$A = \mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}}(hom(q_{2}F_{1},q_{1}F_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{23}}}(hom(q_{2}G_{1},q_{1}G_{2}))\otimes \mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2})))$` .... (diagram with A, B and C)"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\[
\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{%
    \xymatrix{
      {
        \begin{aligned}
          &\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}}(\hom(q_{2}F_{1},q_{1}F_{2}))
          \\
          &\otimes
          \mu_{\Delta_{M_{23}}}(\hom(q_{2}G_{1},q_{1}G_{2}))
          \\
          &\otimes
          \mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(\hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2}))
        \end{aligned}
      }
      \ar[d]
      &
      \\
        {L\circ K
        (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}
          \times\Delta_{M_{23}}
          \times\Delta_{M_{34}}}
        (F_{1}\otimes G_{1}\otimes H_{1}, F_{2}\otimes G_{2} H_{2})
        )} 
      &
      {
        \begin{aligned}
          & L\circ K
          (\mu_{\Delta_{M_{12}}\times\Delta_{M_{23}}}(F_{1}
          \otimes
          G_{1}, F_{2}\otimes
          G_{2}))
          \\
          &\times\mu_{\Delta_{M_{34}}}(\hom(q_{2}H_{1},q_{1}H_{2}))
      \end{aligned}
      }
      }%
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, finally  I will follow your recommendation to use `tikzcd`